# Laravel Mix and Vue custom Loader (iView)

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-2, laravel-mix, iview, iview-ui

I'm kinda new to programming with frameworks like VueJs and webpack is completely new for me. Right now we are working with Laravel 5.6 and laravel mix. I don't know if vue-loader is already in laravel.mix but I'm using a Vue Component Framework called iView and I need to load a custom Loader according to their page how to set it up: https://www.iviewui.com/docs/guide/iview-loader-en

The problem is it just doesn't work.

Nothing gets rendered and I get this error everytime:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined.

Here's my webpack.mix.js

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {

            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'iview-loader',
            options: {
              prefix: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

But when I remove the section with loader: 'vue-loader' then everything gets rendered as it should but the custom loader is still not working since I get errors like this when using the kebap case name.

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

Anyone good at Laravel who knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance.
cheers

Comment: How are you registering the framework components? Can you include where you're importing the framework and/or individual components?

Comment: @btl import iView from 'iview' import 'iview/dist/styles/iview.css' Vue.use(iView)